# scrollTop position of a div with overflow y. Not matching the height of it's children

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

I have a div with a fixed height of 155px and set to scroll it's vertical overflow. 
Inside that div there is an unordered list with a height of 338px.

I'm trying to fins out when a user has scrolled to the bottom of that div.

```
    $('.myDiv').scroll(function(event) {
        var frame = $(event.target);
        console.log(frame.scrollTop() + ", " + $('ol',frame).height() )
    });
```

This is loggin - 210, 338 - I'm not sure how it gets 210 for the scroll position - I would have assumed it would be the same as it's contents - 338.

Can anyone explain why this is the case?

Answer (score 0):

do you have any text in the div?  if so you might want to give it an explicit 'line-height:16px' in CSS